# Giving a FreeBSD talk. How do I pronounce rc.conf?

Tags: freebsd

I was going to do a short talk about FreeBSD, but I'm at a lost at how certain things are customarily said when in person. How would someone say /etc/rc.conf? I think it would be "Arrh Ceee dot Con-fff". "Arrh-Ceee dot config" seems to roll of the tongue a little bit better, but I think I might get laughed at if I said it that way.

Comment: What about if you watch some Youtube vids? Search them using the keywords "FreeBSD rc.conf", and see if some of them edit this file, and check the pronounce :) - https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=FreeBSD+rc.conf

Comment: What's annoying with YouTube with these kinds of videos, most of the time there is no voice audio. If they have to say something they just type it out in a text editor.

Answer (score 3):

"Arrh-Ceee dot config" might "roll off the tongue" for you but it's not accurate and a listener might think that the actual filename you're referring to is `rc.config` rather than `rc.conf`

Comment: Yeah, stick with "Arrh Ceee dot Con-fff".